# Python - How to call the main fuction of a module in another module?

Tags: python, import, arguments, program-entry-point

I am trying to write a python module that calls the main function of another module in its main function.

The module I am writing is called Trial.py and the module that contains the function to be called is called `print_all.py` .

print_all.py is a module is a library called mrtparse. The library can be found [here](https://github.com/YoshiyukiYamauchi/mrtparse).

Note that when I run `print_all.py` in the Linux shell it requires a file (.gz) as argument as follows

```
$ python print_all.py updates.gz
```

`Trial.py` looks something like this:

```
from mrtparse import *
import gzip
import print_all   
import os
from urllib2 import urlopen, URLError, HTTPError

def fn1():
    Bla Bla

def fn2():
    Bla Bla

def main():
    mrtparse.print_all.main(updates.gz)  //I want to do something like this

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

All the modules and the files to be passed as arguments are in the same directory.
It seems like an easy to do thing but I am having such a hard time with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose, you should use:

```python
# ...

import print_all

# ...

def main():
    print_all.main("updates.gz")
```

Honestly, print_all — is not a module and you cannot import it from any place. Notice, that there is no `__init__.py` in `examples`-folder.
Otherwise, you will be able to use `mrtparse.examples.print_all`.
But now `mrtparse` does not see anything in `examples`.

So, you can put `print_all`-script near your script and use it like I show above.

## After that

Main function in print_all have no arguments.
It gets data from command line arguments.

I think, you have two ways:

- Wrong — patch `sys.argv`;
- Right — rewrite main from `print_all`.

### Patch sys.argv (bad way)

```
import sys
sys.argv = sys.argv = [sys.argv[0], 'updates.gz']

# ...

import print_all

# ...

def main():
    print_all.main() 

# ...
```

### Rewrite main()

Post this function into `print_all` and use it instead of `main`.

```
def do_work(filename):

    d = Reader(filename)

    # if you want to use 'asdot+' or 'asdot' for AS numbers,
    # comment out either line below.
    # default is 'asplain'.
    #
    # as_repr(AS_REPR['asdot+'])
    # as_repr(AS_REPR['asdot'])
    for m in d:
        m = m.mrt
        print('---------------------------------------------------')
        if m.err == MRT_ERR_C['MRT Header Error']:
            prerror(m)
            continue
        print_mrt(m)

        if m.err == MRT_ERR_C['MRT Data Error']:
            prerror(m)
            continue
        if m.type == MRT_T['TABLE_DUMP']:
            print_td(m)
        elif m.type == MRT_T['TABLE_DUMP_V2']:
            print_td_v2(m)
        elif ( m.type == MRT_T['BGP4MP']
            or m.type == MRT_T['BGP4MP_ET']):
            print_bgp4mp(m)
```

### Right way

Place `do_work` in your own module or anywhere else in your code.
After that, for example, yout file will be look like this:

```
import sys
from optparse import OptionParser
from datetime import *
from mrtparse import *
from print_all import *
import gzip
import print_all   
import os
from urllib2 import urlopen, URLError, HTTPError


def fn1():
    Bla Bla

def fn2():
    Bla Bla

def do_work(filename):

    d = Reader(filename)

    # if you want to use 'asdot+' or 'asdot' for AS numbers,
    # comment out either line below.
    # default is 'asplain'.
    #
    # as_repr(AS_REPR['asdot+'])
    # as_repr(AS_REPR['asdot'])
    for m in d:
        m = m.mrt
        print('---------------------------------------------------')
        if m.err == MRT_ERR_C['MRT Header Error']:
            prerror(m)
            continue
        print_mrt(m)

        if m.err == MRT_ERR_C['MRT Data Error']:
            prerror(m)
            continue
        if m.type == MRT_T['TABLE_DUMP']:
            print_td(m)
        elif m.type == MRT_T['TABLE_DUMP_V2']:
            print_td_v2(m)
        elif ( m.type == MRT_T['BGP4MP']
            or m.type == MRT_T['BGP4MP_ET']):
            print_bgp4mp(m)


def main():
    do_work('updates.gz') 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: This worked. But what does sys.argv do because I need to call the print_all.py in a loop to run it using different .gz files ? can I place it somewhere inside the Trial.py main function and each iteration change the name of the .gz file ?

Comment: @AhmedAymanIbrahim Of couse, you can change sys.argv anywhere you want — but it is «dirty hack». See an update of my answer, please. I recomend rewrite main, or put do_work into `print_all` (or your script).

Comment: Worked like a charm !!

Answer (score 0):

you could in the script you want to run the main function from place main() in the else statement instead of if **name** then import it in your script and just run.

```
if __name__=='__main__':
     pass
else:
     main()
```

Comment: I tried what you suggested but now I think the main function of Trial.py is not running as I stop seeing any output.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are importing the module print_all separately, you could call print_all.main().

UPDATE: I just looked at the module print_all.py. The first argument will be assumed to be the name of the file itself (print_all). So updates.gz will have to be the second argument. Also make sure you use quotes, since you are passing in a string.

So your code will be:

```
from mrtparse import *
import gzip
import print_all   
import os
from urllib2 import urlopen, URLError, HTTPError

def fn1():
Bla Bla

def fn2():
    Bla Bla

def main():
    print_all.main('print_all.py updates.gz')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: It gives me the following error :

TypeError: main() takes no arguments (1 given)